# ClassCastException by (String) getIn().getBody

Tags: apache-camel

I have this camel route in my RouteBuilder:

```
    @Override
    public void configure() {
            ...
                .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "AfterHttp IN: ${in.headers} - ${in.body}").choice().when(new Predicate() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean matches(Exchange exchange) {
                        String body = (String) exchange.getIn().getBody();
                        return body.contains("output wished");
                    }
                }).to("file://out/wished").end();
    }
```

I dont understand why a ClassCastException occurs at `(String) exchange.getIn().getBody()`

Unfortunately, from the log, I dont get the information, from which class the object of getBody(). is.

```
Execution of JMS message listener failed. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException - java.lang.ClassCastException]
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.ClassCastException
```

It is definitely wrong to just cast to String.  It is stated in doc:

```
Object getBody()
Returns the body of the message as a POJO
```

In case I am just returning true without any logic:

```
                    @Override
                    public boolean matches(Exchange exchange) {
                          return true;
                    }
```

, it is fine and the route is ends as expected(writing the body to directory file://out/wished)

Any advice?

Thank you,
Hadi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
```